# Picking out 1 specific string from a file

Tags: vb.net, file

Ive put in multiple strings in 1 line of a file, so that they are linked together, I have tried multiple ways such as using loops and I was wondering if if anyone could help me, thanks.

in file: swagman (username), samfisher34 (password), sam fisher (fullname)

```
Private Sub btn_login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_login.Click
    Dim Student As New StreamReader("student.txt")
    Dim newline As String

    Dim login As Boolean

    Dim line1 As String
    Dim line2 As String
    ' Reads the files to a string and write the string to the console.

    Dim count As Integer = 20

    For i = 1 To count

        newline = Student.ReadLine

        If txt_login.Text = newline And txt_password.Text = newline Then
            'Checks to see if text is the same in the Files.
            login = True
        End If


        If login = True Then
            Me.Hide()
            StudentMenu.Show()
        End If

    Next

    If login = False Then
        MsgBox("login or password is incorrect")
    End If

    Student.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Visibly not vba code but vb.net, and it is a bad idea to store passwords in plain text btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a really basic code example that I made:

First of all you need to import `System.IO` for the StreamReader

```
    Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader
    Dim strLine As String
    objStreamReader = New StreamReader(File)
    Dim splitresult As Array
    'read the file line for line
    Do Until objStreamReader.Peek = -1
        strLine = objStreamReader.ReadLine
        'split the results (user,pwd,name)
        splitresult = strLine.Split(",")
        If splitresult(0) = user Then
            If splitresult(1) = pwd Then
                MsgBox("Welcome " & splitresult(2))
            End If
    Loop
```

Also please don't store your password as plain text.